# In CRM 2011, using javascript, how can I get the calling entity or form type name?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, xrm

In CRM 2011, using JavaScript, how can I get the calling entity or form type name? For example, if I open an activity, I want to see if I opened this activity from an account form or a contact form etc. I have googled this and I am not finding anything.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case you should check the regarding field - CRM automatically populates this, that should contain the information you require.

Comment: This is fine for activities, I should have added, I need this for contacts, accounts and opportunities also.

Comment: Well the same principle applies, for example for a case you tell if you came from a contact or account by checking the customerid field.

Answer (score 0):

Use

window.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName()

This will only work if you have opened up the entity from the calling entities' form.

It will not work if you open up the entity from the related activities section by on the left.

Basically the parent page should have the entity form loaded in order to use the Xrm.Page.data object.